# Postgres: push unique object into an array of jsonb

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a jsonb array `appliances` into which i am trying to push an object if it does not exists. I am trying it with this query

```
update home
   set appliances = appliances || 
       '{"name": "Television", "uuid": "f6847317-d6fc-476f-8439-3a81f169e9ad"}'
 where uuid = 'f5018a28-fd5f-43df-9d09-4e73da448823'
   and not 
      '{"name": "Television", "uuid": "f6847317-d6fc-476f-8439-3a81f169e9ad"}'::jsonb 
          < @ appliances;
```

But it throws an error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb <@ jsonb[]

The column `appliances` has a datatype of `jsonb[]`. How can i make this query right?

Comment: your DBMS is MySQL or Postgresql ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: from the syntax of the query and the error message, this is clearly Postgres. I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<@` operator and `||` operator over PostgreSQL arrays need both operands to be arrays, not just one of them.

```
update home
   set appliances = appliances || 
       ARRAY['{"name": "Television", "uuid": "f6847317-d6fc-476f-8439-3a81f169e9ad"}'::jsonb]
 where uuid = 'f5018a28-fd5f-43df-9d09-4e73da448823'
   and not 
      ARRAY['{"name": "Television", "uuid": "f6847317-d6fc-476f-8439-3a81f169e9ad"}'::jsonb] 
          <@ appliances;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you: your column is storing an array of `jsonb` (`jsonb[]`), not `jsonb` (that could be a jsonb array or object). So basically you need to either fix your schema do have a `jsonb` column, or use an array operator rather than a jsonb operator.

This should work, since `jsonb` supports equality comparison:

```
and not 
    '{"name": "Television", "uuid": "f6847317-d6fc-476f-8439-3a81f169e9ad"}'::jsonb 
    = any(appliances)
```